# Clarification on how functions can work and correlate with Classes

Tags: c++, function, object, scope

So I was following a tutorial on classes and function when I met this line of code that makes me question my understanding about this subject. Here is something that look like the code:

```
FBullCowGame BCGame;
std::string X
FBullsAndCows Count = BCGame.Counting(X);
```

Now based on my understanding, BCGame is an Object created with the scope of all of the FBullCowGame now what I can't understand is how Counting(X) can send the x value from this cpp file to the function located inside the FBullCowGame. Here's the question:

1) Can the `function()`be used for more than just initializing the function? Like for this instance it seems sending the value of x to make it the function value.

2) Is my understanding of objects flawed or wrong?

3) If the `function()` can be used for sending and receiving value, does it work like it's initialized the function and gets the value of the function? Or is this understanding wrong?

Comment: You had better grab [a good text book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and understand the basics of classes and functions from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I assume that the code is working

```
> 1) Is the function() can be used more than just initializing the
> function? like for this instance it seems sending the value of x to
> make it the function value
```

its not initializing the function (theres no even concept of that in C++) the function was declared and defined with a string parameter on it. when you pass a string on that function(your X) its up to the function if it wants to do something on it (maybe process or something?)

```
2) Is my understanding of objects is flawed or wrong?
```

I think you have follow the first commenter

```
3) If the function() can be used for sending and receiving value does it works like its initialized the function and gets the value of the function? Or is this understanding wrong?
```

you are not understanding what `initialize` is.the function is just receiving what you passed to it(your `X`) and then process it however it wants then returns the value of type `FBullsAndCows` and then assign it to `Count`

Anyway the best suggestion is to get a good book.

**see here:** [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Ok so that means the parameter of that function is now the variable X is that it? Or is it just passing like the meaning giving the value of the variable?

Comment: @HahaWwkw the latter one. its just passing the value of X. unless the parameter is taking a reference of type of string. read about pass-by-reference.

Comment: @HahaWwkw well if that answers your questions or clarifies you. you can mark this as answered. thanks. and welcome to stackoverflow